# sql server import data in tow differentt tables

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm new here and I found to my question no answer:
I import daily via a procedure personal data in a sql database. while import I generate automatically in dependency with the client-id a card number and a wash-id. I write all data in a table, which I would like to change. I want to write the card number in a separate table. The uniqueness in both tables is always the personnel number. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I generate for an imported personell number a cardnumber and a wash-id. I want two store both numbers in a different table. The personell number shoud be stored in both tables. That is what i am trying to describe.